# What is the number 4.9292683…?

Tags: mathematics

Guess the next digits of this number. Where does it came from?

> 4.9292683

Comment: "Floating point" is actually a computing term, describing how a number is represented and stored. In that sense, this isn't a floating point number; it's a string representing a real number.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### 6

It's $\pi e \gamma$

Thanks to the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standardCalc?input=4.9292683).

Comment: You have cheated!

Comment: I prefer to think of it as using the right tool for the job.

Comment: I was kidding. That was the perfect tool for the goal

Comment: 6742 are the next numbers in the expression, and its origins were stated above. You did not actually answer the question Pete. Technically Correct is the Best Kind of Correct - Bureaucrat 1.0, Futurama

Comment: for bonus points, is this number transcendental, rational, or irrational. (answers must include a proof)

Comment: aka integer sequence https://oeis.org/A203816